# ngx-pagination: Angular 6 server side implementation

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I'm attempting to use `ngx-pagination` to implement server side pagination on my Angular 6 application.

I've followed the [documentation](http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/server-paging) to best of my ability but I've encountered the following problems and don't know how to proceed.

**Problems**

1. The component loads and gets the data from the api but is not displayed on render until **after** I would've made two more calls to the api by navigating to the next page and then to previous.
2. Data on page two of the api is not being called.

**Screenshots**

*Initial page load*
[image]

*After back and forth navigation*
[image]

**Sample Code**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';
import { SiteUrls } from '../../services/constants.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

interface IServerResponse {
    items: any[];
    total: number;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sample',
    templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() sample: any = [{}];
    total: number;
    p = 1;
    pagedItems: Observable<any[]>;
    public meta: any = {};
    constructor(private site: SiteUrls, private http: Http, private api: ApiService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPage(1);
    }

    async getPage(page: number) {
        this.pagedItems = this.serverCall(this.sample, page)
            .pipe(tap((res) => {
                this.total = res.total;
                this.p = page;
                console.log('total', this.total, 'page', this.p, 'res', res);

            })).pipe(map((res) => res.items));
    }

    serverCall(sample: any[], page: number): Observable<IServerResponse> {
        this.getsample();
        const perPage = this.meta.per_page;
        const start = (page - 1) * perPage;
        const end = start + perPage;
        return of({
                items: sample.slice(start, end),
                total: this.meta.total
            }).delay(1000);
    }

   private getsample() {
        this.api.get('sample').subscribe((data) => {
            this.sample = data.body.data;
            this.meta = data.body.meta;
        });
    }
}
```

```html
 <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let tran of pagedItems | async | paginate: { itemsPerPage: meta.per_page, currentPage: p, totalItems: meta.total }">
                 
                  <td>
                    {{tran.account.number}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{tran.sender.name}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{tran.recipient.name}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{tran.date | date: 'MMMM dd, yyyy'}}
                  </td>
                  <td style="background-color: antiquewhite">
                    {{tran.subtotal | currency}}
                  </td>
                  <td style="background-color: antiquewhite">
                    {{tran.fee | currency}}
                  </td>
                  <td style="background-color: antiquewhite">
                    <b>{{tran.total | currency}}</b>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="getPage($event)"></pagination-controls>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

`getsample()` is being executed on page load and api returns the data.
For safety, I've changed the method an `async` one so it now looks like this:

```
async getsample() {
   try {
       await this.api.get('sample').subscribe((data) => {
        this.sample = data.body.data;
        this.meta = data.body.meta;
       });
   } catch (error) {}
  }
```

I also implemented the answer given by Brandon but the problem still persist.

Comment: I think the issue is that `this.getsample()` subscription is not yet executed (therefore `sample` and `meta` are not set) and you are trying to read those properties (in `serverCall(...)`). It is `async` issue.

Comment: Thanks @miselking, I had a feeling that might be the problem. I've tried Brandon's suggestion below but it didn't work. Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more problems with your code, one of them is your call to `this.getsample();` that is asynchronous, but you do not wait for the result.

Another thing is that you cannot await observable. Convert it to promise first via `.toPromise()` instead of subscribing, or do not use promises at all and subscribe instead (but only at the very top level - in `ngOnInit` handler).

Using async/await:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getsample(); // move the loading here
    await this.getPage(1);
}

async getPage(page: number) {
    const res = await this.serverCall(this.sample, page);
    this.total = res.total;
    this.p = page;
    console.log('total', this.total, 'page', this.p, 'res', res);
    this.pagedItems = res.items;
}

async serverCall(sample: any[], page: number): Promise<IServerResponse> {
    const perPage = this.meta.per_page;
    const start = (page - 1) * perPage;
    const end = start + perPage;
    return of({
        items: sample.slice(start, end),
        total: this.meta.total
    }).delay(1000).toPromise(); // convert the observable to promise
}

private async getsample() {
    const data = await this.api.get('sample').toPromise(); // and again here
    this.sample = data.body.data;
    this.meta = data.body.meta;
}
```

Comment: this got me a bit closer to a fix, thanks. The problem is that I can't use the AsyncPipe on a Promise, but maybe I don't to. 

The items array of `pagedItems` still returns empty though.

Comment: You definitely can use async pipe on promise

Comment: Alright, because I'm fairly new to this I'll need to walk me through this. 

I've implemented your answer but typescript is complaining that I can't assign type `any` to an Observable. @Martin

Comment: You probably still have some bad typehints in your code (I do not use `Observable` typehint in main, so that error is not caused by it). Btw I think I found your problem. You are calling `getsample()` after you use it in `getPage` method - you need to load it before.

Comment: Check updated answer. If I understand it correctly, you load all data in `getsample` method and then paginate it on client, without actually calling the server again, so you should load it once when initializing (btw this is generally not a good approach for pagination, as you should do this server side and load only displayed items, but that is another story).

Comment: The data is paginated on the server. 10 per page. This particular api returns 2 pages but only the first one is loaded until another call to the api is made.

Comment: Then just move the getsample call as the first line of getPage method

Comment: Done. Just need to fix the `InvalidPipeArgument` error in the template and all should be well. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's an async/await issue.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getPage(1);
}
```

should be:

```
async ngOnInit() {
  await this.getPage(1);
}
```

Otherwise, `this.pagedItems` will be null until `serverCall()` completes.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Brandon but unfortunately, this did not resolve the problem.